# Android split string into 2 strings

Tags: java, string, split

I have

`String s = "hello=goodmorning,2,1"`

can somebody help me with the code on how to split `s` to equal the following:

```
String s2 = "hello"
String s3 = "goodmorning"
string s4 = "2,1"
```

Comment: post your attempts and define the logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "hello=goodmorning,2,1"

String[] str = s.split("=");  //now str[0] is "hello" and str[1] is "goodmorning,2,1"

String str1 = str[0];  //hello

String[] str2 = str[1].split(",");  //now str2[0] is "goodmorning" and str2[1] is "2,1"

String str3 = str2[0];  //goodmorning
String str4 = str2[1];  //2,1
```

Output:

```
str1 = hello;
str3 = goodmorning;
str4 = 2,1;
```

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin add

```
var s = "hello=goodmorning,2,1"
var str = s.split("=")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s = "hello=goodmorning 2 1 3 4";
 String[] str = s.split(" "); 
 String str1 = str[0]; 
 String new1 =s.replace(str1,"");
 System.out.println(new1);
```

Output is  2 1 3 4